# Understanding getIntExtra() arguments

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);$$

  // pull the turtle's ID out of the intent that the MainActivity used to load me
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("turtle_id", R.id.leo);
    String text = "";
    if (id == R.id.leo) {
        text = TURTLE_DETAILS[0];
    } else if (id == R.id.mike) {
        text = TURTLE_DETAILS[1];
    } else if (id == R.id.don) {
        text = TURTLE_DETAILS[2];
    } else { // if (id == R.id.raph)
        text = TURTLE_DETAILS[3];
    }
```

I cannot work out the line

```
int id = intent.getIntExtra("turtle_id", R.id.leo);
```

I cannot see why `R.id.leo` has been specified? `turtle_id` is the name but I am not sure the point of `R.id.leo`.

Snippet of `MainActivity.java`

```
    /*
     * Called when the Details activity finishes running and comes back to here.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    /*
     * Called when the user clicks on the large TMNT image button.
     * Loads the DetailsActivity for more information about that turtle.
     */
    public void onClickTurtleImage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

        RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.turtle_group);
        int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        intent.putExtra("turtle_id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /*
     * This method is called when the user chooses one of the turtle radio buttons.
     * In this code we set which turtle image is visible on the screen in the ImageView.
     */
    public void pickTurtle(View view) {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.turtle);
        if (view.getId() == R.id.leo) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tmntleo);
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.mike) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tmntmike);
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.don) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tmntdon);
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.raph) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tmntraph);
        }
    }
}
```

`DetailsActivity.java`

```
/*
 * CS 193A, Winter 2015, Marty Stepp
 * This app is a continuation of our TMNT app from last week.
 * Today's version adds a second activity and launches that activity using an Intent.
 * This file represents the Java code for the second activity.
 */

package com.example.stepp.layoutfun;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {
    /*
     * Constant array of data about each of the four turtles.
     * (This is not the most idiomatic way to store such information,
     * but we'll come back to it later.)
     */
    private static final String[] TURTLE_DETAILS = {
            ""/*Long Story but not relevant for the question*/
    };

    /*
     * Called when the activity first gets created.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        // pull the turtle's ID out of the intent that the MainActivity used to load me
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("turtle_id", R.id.leo);
        String text = "";
        if (id == R.id.leo) {
            text = TURTLE_DETAILS[0];
        } else if (id == R.id.mike) {
            text = TURTLE_DETAILS[1];
        } else if (id == R.id.don) {
            text = TURTLE_DETAILS[2];
        } else { // if (id == R.id.raph)
            text = TURTLE_DETAILS[3];
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.turtle_info);
        tv.setText(text);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/turtle_group"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/leo"
            android:onClick="pickTurtle"
            android:text="Leo"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mike"
            android:onClick="pickTurtle"
            android:text="Mike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/don"
            android:onClick="pickTurtle"
            android:text="Don"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/raph"
            android:onClick="pickTurtle"
            android:text="Raph"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/turtle"
        android:onClick="onClickTurtleImage"
        android:src="@drawable/tmntleo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Used tutorial is [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/lectures.shtml).

Comment: You should place code into your question next time.

Comment: But only the relevant please. @DamianKozlak was it your edit, to add also the unrelevant? I´ll fix it.

Comment: @SebastianWalla yes, check history

Comment: To avoid possible downvotes in the future, please look first in the android api or if you did, show us your research effort. But I´m impressed what a good first question this is.

Comment: @SebastianWalla I did look but didnt find this, just found lots of capital letters, obviously not used to this enough

Comment: So you maybe were on the right page, but before the methods the constants ("the lot of capital letters") are listed. An easy and fast way to find your method is to search the website. In mozzila the shortcut for this would be ctrl+f .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for the `getIntExtra` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) is as follows:

> Retrieve extended data from the intent.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `name`    The name of the desired item.
>
> `defaultValue`    the value to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given name.
>
> **Returns**
>
> the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or the default value if none was found.

So in your example, `id` will be assigned the integer value associated with the key `turtle_id` if that key exists in the `Intent`, and will be assigned the integer value `R.id.leo` if not. Typically, this is used so that sensible defaults are provided if a consumer fails to pass in the requisite information when starting this `Activity`. In your particular case, this behavior can be interpreted as: "if the caller forgot to tell me which turtle was selected when starting this `Activity`, assume it was Leo."

Comment: I looked through the online documentation but didnt find this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer of @stkent is correct.
The right parameter is like a backup, if no value can be found under `"turtle_id"`.
 In addition as a general source of information have a look in the [Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) concerning your question. In many cases you will find there a short and genuine answer, how the methods work.